# Make predictions after merging estimated models in a dataframe for all observations using broom and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I am working in a modeling problem where I have to estimate multiple models per group using specific variables. After having all models per groups I need to compute the estimated values (fitted values) and standard errors (se) for all of them. I found we can use `broom` and `dplyr` for this. So, I sketched next code using `iris` data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
#Data
data("iris")
#Code
iris2 <- iris %>% group_by(Species)
```

Data `iris2` has a group based on `Species`. With this I compute the different models using next code:

```
#Models
models <- iris2 %>% 
  do(
  model1 = lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, data = .),
  model2 = lm(Sepal.Width~Petal.Width, data = .),
  model3 = lm(Petal.Width~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data = .),
  model4 = lm(Petal.Width~Petal.Length+Sepal.Length, data = .))
```

Which produces:

```
models
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  Species    model1 model2 model3 model4
  <fct>      <list> <list> <list> <list>
1 setosa     <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>  
2 versicolor <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>  
3 virginica  <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>
```

All is fine. Now, I need to compute the predictions for the entire dataset `iris2` using the four models. I used a merge approach to add the models to the `iris2` dataframe:

```
#Merge with original data
Merged <- iris2 %>%
  left_join(models)
```

At this point, the data has all the models but I am not sure of how to proceed to compute the fitted values and standard error. In the end I would like to have two additional columns per each model like `predict.mod1` and `se.mod1` until `predict.mod4` and `se.mod4` for all the observations in `iris2`.

This is my main issue as I do not know how to use `predict()` to take each `model1`, `model2`, `model3` and `model4` to compute both fitted and se values. I know I can use `predict()` and `predict(model,data,se=T)$$se.fit` to obtain the values in an isolated dataframe with one model but in this case I have multiple models after the merge action.

I have checked some posts around the site and they use `mutate(result = map2(fit, data, predict))` to create the estimations. I tried a similar approach but did not work.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @akrun Many thanks sir, I am new using that functions. Could you please provide an answer using that for both fitted and se? King regards!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of separating the dataset and joining, could create the models in the same data after nesting

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
iris1 <- iris %>% 
    nest_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate(model1 = list(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = data)),
           model2 = list(lm(Sepal.Width~Petal.Width, data = data)), 
           model3 = list(lm(Petal.Width~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data = data)),
           model4 = list(lm(Petal.Width~Petal.Length+Sepal.Length, data = data)))
```

-output

```
iris1
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise:  Species
#  Species              data model1 model2 model3 model4
#  <fct>      <list<tibble>> <list> <list> <list> <list>
#1 setosa           [50 × 4] <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>  
#2 versicolor       [50 × 4] <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>  
#3 virginica        [50 × 4] <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>
```

---

Create the columns in a similar pipeline as used by @LMc except that the 'data' can be passed in (which is not really needed here unless there is a different data)

```
iris1 %>% 
 mutate(across(starts_with('model'), 
    list(se = ~ list(tidy(.)$std.error), 
        predict = ~ list(predict(., data)))))
# A tibble: 3 x 14
# Rowwise:  Species
#  Species              data model1 model2 model3 model4 model1_se model1_predict model2_se model2_predict model3_se model3_predict model4_se
#  <fct>      <list<tibble>> <list> <list> <list> <list> <list>    <list>         <list>    <list>         <list>    <list>         <list>   
#1 setosa           [50 × 4] <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <dbl [2]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [2]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [3]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [3]>
#2 versicolor       [50 × 4] <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <dbl [2]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [2]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [3]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [3]>
#3 virginica        [50 × 4] <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <lm>   <dbl [2]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [2]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [3]> <dbl [50]>     <dbl [3]>
# … with 1 more variable: model4_predict <list>
```

---

From the nested data, it can be `unest`ed.  Here, we are `select`ing columns that have the same length (`model` columns are different structure)

```
library(tidyr)
iris1 %>% 
 mutate(across(starts_with('model'), 
  list(se = ~ list(tidy(.)$std.error), 
    predict = ~ list(predict(., data))))) %>% 
 ungroup %>% 
 select(Species, data, ends_with('predict')) %>%
 unnest(-Species)
# A tibble: 150 x 9
#   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width model1_predict model2_predict model3_predict model4_predict
#   <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2           5.06           3.39          0.254          0.241
# 2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2           4.71           3.39          0.232          0.229
# 3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2           4.85           3.39          0.221          0.200
# 4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2           4.78           3.39          0.212          0.228
# 5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2           5.12           3.39          0.248          0.235
# 6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4           5.33           3.56          0.281          0.310
# 7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3           4.99           3.47          0.217          0.211
# 8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2           4.99           3.39          0.245          0.252
# 9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2           4.64           3.39          0.195          0.199
#10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1           4.78           3.31          0.233          0.246
# … with 140 more rows
```

---

Or using the `se` from `predict`

```
iris1 %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('model'), 
   list(se = ~ list(predict(., data, se = TRUE)$se.fit), 
         predict = ~ list(predict(., data))))) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-matches('^model\\d+$')) %>%
  unnest(-Species)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but I would like to compute the predictions using that models. That is why I merged data. I need to use `predict()`. Could you help with that?

Comment: Also I would need to extract the values for predicted and standard values in new columns.

Comment: @StackGuy sorry, was working on other stuff.  Will take a look

Comment: Many thanks for the update, my issue and the reason why I merged into `Merged` is because I would need to add to that dataframe the predictions using `predict()` and errors using `predict(.,se=TRUE)$se.fit` into new columns as pred.mod1,...,pred.mod4 and so on. Your solutions are really nice but I can have the entire data (150 rows). Is there any way you can help me with that? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @StackGuy I updated the post with `unnest`.

Comment: @StackGuy The Se was creatd from the model.  If we change it to from the predict, it can also be created as columns

Comment: Is there any way to be sure that data will keep its order in rows after unnesting?

Comment: @StackGuy it will be the same order.  But, if you want to double check.  Can create a row number column in the initiall data i.e. `iris %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% nest_by(Species) %>%.`